# HighMaps - need to make datalabels clickable

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the small U.S. map in HighMaps and I want each state and it's datalabel to open up a new URL when clicked.  I have the state working, but the label does not work.

this is what I tried:

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function(e) {
                                const url = e.target.point.value;
                                window.open(url);
                            }
                        }
                    },
          datalabels: {
                        events: {
                            click: function(e) {
                                const url = e.target.point.value;
                                window.open(url);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/sfjeld/zcsxobfa/12/ for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `this.value` instead of `e.target.point.value`:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          const url = this.value;
          window.open(url);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6gpL57nf/

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could use:

```
e.point.properties.hasc
```

For get the value from the clicked point.

Code:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          const url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + e.point.properties.hasc;
          window.open(url);
        }
      }
    },
  }
},
```

You can check other values using this path:

```
console.log(e.point.properties);
```

The full code is in [this forked jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/49kowxbc/)

Comment: Thanks @marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes.  I need to pull the URL from the HTML table. I put www.google.com as a placeholder, but each state will have a different URL.